Jenkins choice parameter output not checked items
New to Jenkins and currently working on a job that needs a parameter with a list of items and a "false/true" state for each. My idea was to do this with an extended choice parameter but the "output" of that is a list with only the items that are checked. Is there a way to do something similar but also get a list with the items that are not checked?
Am aware of other ways to manage this but I am just interested if the idea presented above is possible.


The output value for Test_p  would be: "CTA,RSP2".
Looking on how to also get "EM,SPM,PRIME" as unchecked values

One way to solve this would be to define the available choices in a variablle and then calculate the difference between what's selected and what is not selected:
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field testPChoices = 'EM,CTA,SPM,RSP2,PRIME'

pipeline {
    agent none
    parameters {
        extendedChoice(
            name: 'Test_p',
            type: 'PT_CHECKBOX',
            value: testPChoices,
        )
    }
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo "Selected ${params.Test_p}"
                echo "Not selected ${testPChoices.split(',') - params.Test_p.split(',')}"
            }
        }
    }
}

